# Extract n years m months and x days pattern using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match n years m months and x days pattern using regex. `n years`, `m months`, `x days` and `and` may or may not be in the string. For exact match i am able to extract this using the regex:

```
re.search(r'(?:\d+ year(s?))?\s*(?:\d+ month(s?))?\s*(?:\d+ day(s?))?', '2 years 25 days')
```

which returns 2 years 25 days, but if there is addtional text in the string I don't get the match like:

```
re.search(r'(?:\d+ year(s?))?\s*(?:\d+ month(s?))?\s*(?:\d+ day(s?))?', 'in 2 years 25 days')
```

retunrs ''

I tried this:

```
re.search(r'.*(?:\d+ year(s?))?\s*(?:\d+ month(s?))?\s*(?:\d+ day(s?))?.*', 'in 2 years 25 days')
```

whih returns the whole string, but I dont want the additional text.

Comment: When you try **re.search(r'(?:\d+ year(s?))?\s*(?:\d+ month(s?))?\s*(?:\d+ day(s?))?', 'in 2 years 25 days')** what is output?

Comment: Because your regex consists of only optional elements. You use `re.search`, and it returns the first match, the empty string before the first char. Make your pattern non-optional, or get all matches with `re.finditer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an empty string with the last pattern as all the parts in the regex are optional, so it will also match an empty string.

If all the parts are optional but you want to match at least 1 of them, you can use a leading assertion.

```
\b(?=\d+ (?:years?|months?|days?)\b)(?:\d+ years?)?(?:\s*\d+ months?)?(?:\s*\d+ days?)?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?=\d+ (?:years?|months?|days?)\b)` Assert to the right 1+ digits and 1 of the alternatives
- `(?:\d+ years?)?` Match 1+ digits, space and year or years
- `(?:\s*\d+ months?)?` Same for months
- `(?:\s*\d+ days?)?` Same for years
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y06FHE/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GNCkwo)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r'\b(?=\d+ (?:years?|months?|days?)\b)(?:\d+ years?)?(?:\s*\d+ months?)?(?:\s*\d+ days?)?\b'
m = re.search(pattern, 'in 2 years 25 days')
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

Output

```
2 years 25 days
```

Comment: @hc_dev I am not sure why you got a downvote, maybe because it returns separate parts or day instead of days. You will get my vote for showing an alternative to a regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since `years`, `months`, `days` are temporal units, you could use the [pint](https://pypi.org/project/Pint/) module for that.

### Parse temporal units with pint

See the [String parsing](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#string-parsing) tutorial and related features used:

- printing quantities, see [String formatting](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#sec-string-formatting)
- converting quantities, see [Converting to different units](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#converting-to-different-units)

```
from pint import UnitRegistry

ureg = UnitRegistry()

temporal_strings = '2 years and 25 days'.split('and')  # remove and split
quantities = [ureg(q) for q in temporal_strings]  # parse quantities
# [<Quantity(2, 'year')>, <Quantity(25, 'day')>]

# print the quantities separately
for q in quantities:
    print(q)

# get the total days
print(f"total: {sum(quantities)}")
print(f"total days: {sum(quantities).to('days')}")
```

Output printed:

```
2 year
25 day
total: 2.0684462696783026 year
total days: 755.5 day
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import re
match =re.search(r'(?:\d+ year(s?))?\s*(?:\d+ month(s?))?\s*(?:\d+ day(s?))', 'in 2 years 25 days')
if match:
 print(match.group())
```

Output:

```
2 years 25 days
```

Comment: @hc_dev I have updated this please check it